# pandas aggregate items as list and filter based on legth

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Let me show with an example, I have this dataframe:

[image]

I want to end up with to this dataframe: (so I group by "column_1" and "last_column" and I aggregate by "column_2" to get the items as a list)

[image]

If you notice, when column_1 = 'yes' it doesn't appear that row, **SINCE THE LENGTH OF THE RESULT IS 1**.

I'm able to filter and aggregate as a list separately, but not both together...

```
df.groupby(
['column_1', 'last_column']
)['column_2'].agg(list).filter(lambda x : len(x)<2)
```

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'column_1': ['no', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes'], 
    'column_2': ['spain', 'france', 'italy', 'germany', 'spain', 'france', 'italy', 'germany'], 
    "last_column": ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas group by and aggregate as list ONLY when the result of the length of the group by is > 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74800619/pandas-group-by-and-aggregate-as-list-only-when-the-result-of-the-length-of-the)

Comment: Hi @gtomer that's my question!! it's a very similar one, step by step haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```py
df_out = df.groupby(["column_1", "last_column"])["column_2"].agg(list)
df_out = df_out.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda y: len(y) > 1)

print(df_out.reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
  column_1 last_column          column_2
0       no           A  [italy, germany]
1       no           B   [spain, france]
```

---

Dataframe used:

```
  column_1 column_2 last_column
0       no    spain           B
1       no   france           B
2       no    italy           A
3       no  germany           A
4      yes    spain           B
5      yes   france           B
6      yes    italy           B
7      yes  germany           B
```

Comment: That's just brilliant. This is what I was looking for.  I will take a look to what level does, never saw it before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?:

```
df2 = df.groupby(
['column_1', 'last_column'], as_index=False
)['column_2'].agg(list)
df2['len'] = df2['column_2'].apply(lambda x : len(x))
df2 = df2[df2['len']<=2]
df2
```

Comment: mm I see what you doing but that's not what I mean. Not regarding the length of the "column_2"

Comment: So which length do you want to filter by?